# PHP String Split

Tags: php, split, unpack

I need to split a string into chunks of 2,2,3,3 characters and was able to do so in Perl by using unpack:

```
unpack("A2A2A3A3", 'thisisloremipsum');
```

However the same function does not work in PHP, it gives this output:

```
Array
(
    [A2A3A3] => th
)
```

How can I do this by using unpack? I don't want to write a function for it, it should be possible with unpack but how?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting the manual page of [**`unpack`**](https://www.php.net/unpack) :

> `unpack()` works slightly different
> from Perl as the unpacked data is
> stored in an associative array.
>
> To accomplish this you have to
> **name the different format codes** and **separate them by a slash `/`**.

Which means that, using something like this :

```
$a = unpack("A2first/A2second/A3third/A3fourth", 'thisisloremipsum');
var_dump($a);
```

You'll get the following output :

```
array
  'first' => string 'th' (length=2)
  'second' => string 'is' (length=2)
  'third' => string 'isl' (length=3)
  'fourth' => string 'ore' (length=3)
```

Comment: Thanks! I separated them by a slash but could not figure out the naming thing.

print_r(unpack("A2/A2/A3/A3", 'thisisloremipsum'));

as this one is not working.. it could at least create an index by itself. :/ Thanks again..

Comment: Yeah, I suppose it would be useful/helpful if it could create a numerical index by default... but that's not the way it works, so we don't have much of a choice ^^

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this function, but according to the documentation, the `A` character means "SPACE-padded string". So I'd hazard a guess that it's only taking the first two characters of the first word.

Have you tried `unpack("A2A2A3A3", 'this is lorem ipsum');`  ?