# How to parse all attributes of tag from string into array using php?

Tags: php, regex, xml-parsing, attributes, html-parsing

I have a html string like...

```
<match id="18" srs="ICC Womens World Cup Qualifier, 2010" mchDesc="BANW vs PMGW" mnum="4th Match">
```

Using **php** how  i can split/decode/parse this string as a accessible object(key value pair) such as....

```
array(
    "id"=>"18", 
    "srs"=>"ICC Womens World Cup Qualifier, 2010", 
    "mchDesc"=>"BANW vs PMGW", 
    "mnum"=>"4th Match"
);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 18
    [srs] => ICC Womens World Cup Qualifier, 2010
    [mchDesc] => BANW vs PMGW
    [mnum] => 4th Match
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP String Split](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599230/php-string-split)

Comment: Take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: Please see the specification of both question @Vintesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Should Work.

```
(\w+)\=\"([a-zA-Z0-9 ,.\/&%?=]+)\"
```

Code PHP:

```
<?php
$re = '/(\w+)\=\"([a-zA-Z0-9 ,.\/&%?=]+)\"/m';
$str = '<match id="18" srs="ICC Womens World Cup Qualifier, 2010" mchDesc="BANW vs PMGW" mnum="4th Match">
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

$c = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);

print_r($c);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 18
    [srs] => ICC Womens World Cup Qualifier, 2017
    [mchDesc] => BANW vs PMGW
    [mnum] => 4th Match, Group B
    [type] => ODI
    [vcity] => Colombo
    [vcountry] => Sri Lanka
    [grnd] => Colombo Cricket Club Ground
    [inngCnt] => 0
    [datapath] => google.com/j2me/1.0/match/2017/
)
```

Ideone: http://ideone.com/OQ7Ko1

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/lyMmKF/7

Comment: everything ok but when string become "<match id="18" type="ODI" srs="ICC Womens World Cup Qualifier, 2017" mchDesc="BANW vs PMGW" mnum="4th Match, Group B" vcity="Colombo" vcountry="Sri Lanka" grnd="Colombo Cricket Club Ground" inngCnt="0" datapath="http://google.com/j2me/1.0/match/2017/2017_ICC_WOMENS_WORLDCUP_QUALIFIER/BANW_PMGW_FEB07/">"  then datapath cannot parse.

Comment: @masumbillah fixed. ^_^ and added support for "google.com/j2me/1.0/match/2017/index.php?=potato" and "google.com/j2me/1.0/match/2017/index.php?=potato&?watermelon=true"

Comment: If a pattern starts with `\w+`, you don't need to put a word boundary before. But if you want to reduce the number of steps, you can put one at the very beginning of the pattern (outside of the parenthesis).

Comment: but i can not parse datapath="dhttp://google.com/j2me/1.0/match/2017/2017_ICC_WOMENS_WORLDCUP_QUALIFIER/BANW_PMGW_FEB07/" @Edulynch

Comment: I think re should be (\w+)\=\"([a-zA-Z0-9 ,._:\/&%?=]+)\"  @Edulynch

Comment: The `m` pattern modifier is of no benefit to your pattern.  The double quotes in your pattern do not need to be escaped.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMAttr`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domattr.php):

```
$str = '<match id="18" srs="ICC Womens World Cup Qualifier, 2010" mchDesc="BANW vs PMGW" mnum="4th Match">';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($str);

$result = [];

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('match')->item(0)->attributes as $attr) {
    $result[$attr->name] = $attr->value;
}

print_r($result);
```

The main advantage is that it doesn't care if attributes values are enclosed between single or double quotes (or no quotes at all), if there are spaces before or after the equal sign.